# C# Inheritance between classes, lists and objects

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, object, controls

I have created a list that contains an object, that contains a list of objects. I want to retrieve the values from an inherited/child class object, that is in the parent classes list/object. Its a bit confusing to explain my code below should help. Maybe Linq might be the solution? Im not to sure. Many thanks.

**RelocationActivityForm Class** -- This creates a new object using the inherited Relocation activity class.

```
 private Vehicle selectedVehicle;

            selectedVehicle = (Vehicle)mainFormRego.SelectedItem; // Gets the selected item from a listbox

            selectedVehicle.ActivityList.Add(new Relocation() // create an object for the selected vehicle, inside the activitylist (list) creating a new object using the Relocation class.
            {
                Date = date, // In activity class
                Name = name, // In activity class
                Type = "Relocation", // In activity class
                Start = start,// In relocation class
                End = end, // In relocation class
                Distance = distance, // In relocation class
                Cost = cost // In activity class
            });
            ViewVehicleForm.Form.updateViewVehicle(); // Method updates textbox display.
            Hide(); // Form hidden

        }
```

**Vehicle Class**

```
namespace VehicleSystem
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Vehicle
    {
        private int dailyCharge;
        private int year;
        private string model;
        private string make;
        private string rego;
        private List<Activity> _activityList = new List<Activity>();

        public string Rego { get => rego; set => rego = value; }
        public string Make { get => make; set => make = value; }
        public string Model { get => model; set => model = value; }
        public int Year { get => year; set => year = value; }
        public int DailyCharge { get => dailyCharge; set => dailyCharge = value; } // Creating an ativity list for each vehicle
        internal List<Activity> ActivityList { get => _activityList; set => _activityList = value; 
         }

    }
}
```

**Activity Class**

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Activity
    {
        // Relocation Activity
        private DateTime _date;
        private string _name;
        private string _type;
        private decimal _cost;

        public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value; }
        public string Type { get => _type; set => _type = value; }
        public decimal Cost { get => _cost; set => _cost = value; }
        public DateTime Date { get => _date; set => _date = value; }
    }
```

**Relocation Class**

```
    class Relocation : Activity
    {
        private string start;
        private string end;
        private int distance;

        public string Start { get => start; set => start = value; }
        public string End { get => end; set => end = value; }
        public int Distance { get => distance; set => distance = value; }
    }
```

Using this I want to get the items from the Relocation class, from the ActivityList from the vehicle. I can get the items from the ActivityList (shown below by calling this statement), but I cant get the activities/items that are stored using the Relocation class.

```
 private void viewVehicleActivityData_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = viewVehicleActivityData.CurrentCell.RowIndex; // Getting the datagridview index of a row
            MessageBox.Show(selectedVehicle.ActivityList[x].Name); // Using it to get the name
        }
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you saying that you have a list of `Activity` objects and you would like the subsequence of that list which are all the `Relocation` objects?  That's the `OfType<Relocation>` sequence operator. If that's not what you want then can you clarify the question?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.  "I cant get the activities/items that are stored using the Relocation class" is unclear.. `Relocation` type does not store or have members that relate to Activities/Items.

Comment: I may be presumptuous here, but I think what you're looking for is a means to determine on, or correlate, `RowIndex` to `selectedVehicle.ActivityList.OfType<Relocation>()` in that you'll need to resolve the indexing against `selectedVechicle.ActivityList`? is that the issue you're facing?

Comment: @BrettCaswell yes thats what I mean. sorry guys

Comment: I am trying to get the items from the relocation sub class of activity. I am creating an object that uses the Relocation class but I cannot get the items from that class only from the activity class.

Comment: @BrettCaswell how do I get an item, e.g end?

Comment: @EricLippert yes thats what Im after but how do I get a specific item such as end?

Comment: I've added an answer for your scenario, but I'll say this approach is probably not one I would use.  As this scope is event-driven, you should consider an approach that uses `sender` and/or `e` arguments for this scoped functionality.. and avoid referencing to `CurrentCell` and (if possible) `selectedVehicle.ActivityList` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Is because your **ActivityList** is of type **List<Activity>** and the **Relocation** is a sub class of **Activity** so you can't see if you use as Activity, you can try to cast the Activity from the list into Relocation.

make sure do proper checking before casting see here examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast

example:

```
if (selectedVehicle.ActivityList[x] is Relocation relocation) {
   MessageBox.Show(relocation.End);
}
```

Comment: So what would I need to write to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are various implementations you can use here.  I do think the general notion is covered by @ebv's answer and reference to type casting, but I'll include a snippet for your scenario. (in reference to 'How do I get `End`' in your comments)

---

This answer's implementation will use the [as operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator)

which —

> explicitly converts the result of an expression to a given reference or nullable value type

It will return `null` if the conversion fails.

As such, we'll use a [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) (i.e. `?`) and [null-coalescing operators (right-associative)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) (i.e. `??`) to handle the condition of `null` in this conversion, or otherwise return `End` if the conversion occurs.

```
private void viewVehicleActivityData_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int x = viewVehicleActivityData.CurrentCell.RowIndex; // Getting the datagridview index of a row
    MessageBox.Show((selectedVehicle.ActivityList[x] as Relocation)?.End ?? "Activity is not Relocation"); // Using it to get the name
}
```

##### Alternatively

In your given sample snippets, **All** activities are `Relocation` type.

And if that is indeed the case, you would need only implicit cast here —

```
private void viewVehicleActivityData_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int x = viewVehicleActivityData.CurrentCell.RowIndex; // Getting the datagridview index of a row
    MessageBox.Show(((Relocation)selectedVehicle.ActivityList[x]).End); // Using it to get the name
}
```

Comment: some of these operators are introduced in more recent c# languages. Thus, this implementation may require c# 8.0